# Video in html5 Firefox os

Tags: html, firefox, video, operating-system, local

I have a problem:
I create a firefox os apps and I want to add a video. But when I write this:

```
<video controls src="video.webm" autoplay poster="posterimage.jpg"> </video>
```

> Sorry, your browser does not seem to support embedded videos. You can still download it and view it with your favorite video player !

And I test in my phone I can't move in the video (example: the video is 1:00 and I click in 2:00, nothing moves).

Comment: Can you please more clearly describe your issue and include the minimal relevant code? It would also be good if you can post the error message in English.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in canuse  http://caniuse.com/#feat=video or in mozilla doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats if  the browser you are using (or which version) support html5 video tag.

In detail in Mozilla Doc you find the table  `Browser compatibility` where for the main browser you can see the level of compatibility.

for Firefox OS  there is this note

> In Firefox OS 1.0.1, when detecting  support for different
>   formats, HTMLMediaElement.prototype.canPlayType incorrectly reports
>   true for h.264 video whereas in actual fact h.264 is not supported. In
>   Firefox OS 1.1 this problem has been fixed.

and other detail.